# How to run command on list and have PsExec or Powershell automatically jump to the next item on this list

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a list of computers in 'computers.txt'.

I am trying to run an .exe on each remote computer name in a list.  I have to execute a .ps1 script on each computer that installs the .exe properly.  In PsExec, I have to press enter after a minute or 2 in between each computer name.  This will go through the list of remote computers and run an .exe that is on each computer.
In PowerShell, only the first computer runs the .exe and the rest don't do anything.

Is there any way to go through the list without having to press Enter between computer name when the script is running?  I want it all to run automatically.

Here is what I am using in PsExec.

```
psexec -s @C:\App\computers.txt cmd /c "Powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass && PowerShell -noninteractive -file "C:\SpeedInstall.ps1""
```

Here is what I am trying in PowerShell

```
$a = Get-Content "C:\App\computers.txt"
foreach($line in $a) {
psexec -s \\$line cmd /c "Powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass && PowerShell -noninteractive -file C:\SpeedInstall.ps1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/d` switch with PSExec to make it not wait for the previous command to finish before moving on to the next one.  There is a tradeoff in that you don't get to see any error messages that the command may generate, but it allows you to get through your list much much more quickly.  Your command will look like this:

```
$a = Get-Content "C:\App\computers.txt"
foreach($line in $a) {
  psexec -s -d \\$line cmd /c "Powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass && PowerShell -noninteractive -file C:\SpeedInstall.ps1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even want to use `psexec`? How about `PSRemoting`?

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\computers.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
Copy-Item -Path C:\install.exe -Destination \\$Computer\c$\Windows\Temp\install.exe
}

$Script =
@"
# Write down your installation script here
& C:\install.exe /silent
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Install -Name Setting -Value 1 -Type DWord
"@

$ScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($Script)


$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computers -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile)
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```